# How to build jar files from source files checked out from Eclipse CVS?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I have checked out the Java Nebula source files from Eclipse CVS onto my local hard drive. But how do I build these newly checked out source files from the CVS into jar files so that I can use them in my other projects?

I also intend to import the source files into jar files so that I can import to plug-ins such as the GWT designer in eclipse so that I can use them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you downloaded the sources because of this: "We are sorry but currently all Nebula-Builds are broken. You can get access to the source by directly checking it out from CVS"  -- I hope you checked out an older version

Comment: Yes, I saw that message and thought I have to build them manually. Am I right? I checked out directly from the Nebula's project folder in the Eclipse CVS. Is this the old or new version? Which one should I use?

Comment: @xEnOn: The message said: "Something is wrong with the actual version, we are not able to build it" - so there is the danger of spending time to compile something that (maybe) does not work.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea where to even start from to build the sources files after checking out from CVS in Eclipse. The nightly build jar files on Nebula don't seem to have all the files that the source packages appear to have. That's why I thought I could try to build from the sources myself.

Comment: I have browsed the CSV a bit: there is build directory (org.eclipse.nebula.build/) containing a build.bat file. May this helps you to start.

Comment: Sadly, the build.bat throws exception whenever I run it. I remember I read somewhere that the build directory is for an older version or something. It is kind of confusing. I cannot find enough documentation for setting up Nebula unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way in eclipse to build a jar of the project.

**Right click on Project --> Export --> Java --> Jar** and just check the Nebula related sources of which you have to make the jar file.

Comment: You say "check the Nebula related sources of which you have to make the jar file", but the only listed sources shown are from other, unrelated, projects.  Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the nebula source are eclipse plugins.  You use File>Export...>Deployable plug-ins and fragments.  That will export the plugin as a jar that can be installed into eclipse or RCP.